# Create a table without border

Tags: java, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

I've managed to create a table:

```
//I create the table here and the default name is table1
XTextTable xTT = (XTextTable) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTextTable.class, oInt);
xTT.initialize(1, 1);
```

However, this create the table with a default border. I would like to create this table without it.

This property is setted by the image

[image]

Comment: Or maybe remove the border after created the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the table and then set the border width to 0.  Here is a Python example from https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@api.openoffice.org/msg07317.html:

```
borderLine = BorderLine()
borderLine.OuterLineWidth = 0

tableBorder = table.getPropertyValue("TableBorder")
tableBorder.VerticalLine = borderLine
tableBorder.HorizontalLine = borderLine
tableBorder.LeftLine = borderLine
tableBorder.RightLine = borderLine
tableBorder.TopLine = borderLine
tableBorder.BottomLine = borderLine
table.setPropertyValue("TableBorder", tableBorder)
```

For a related Java example, search for "TableBorder" on this page: http://api.libreoffice.org/examples/DevelopersGuide/FirstSteps/HelloTextTableShape.java

Comment: Thanks man! That's what a needed. I just had to convert to TableBorder when I get the property.